# "error":"undefined method "some_id' for #" in ruby datamapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I have two ruby models with the following relationship (using datamapper):

```
class Klass

  expose :id, :kid

  property :id, Serial
  property :date, DateTime
  has 1, :kid

class KID

  expose :id, :klass

  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :klass
```

When I try to retrieve the Klass object, I get an error:

```
"error":"undefined method `klass_id' for #"
```

All the objects are created fine in the database.

Any help with this?